# Can I use SGD with Multinomial Naive Bayes?

Tags: scikit-learn, bayesian, cross-validation, text-classification, naivebayes

I'd like to understand if I can and if it's valid approach to train your MNB model with SGD. My application is text classification. In [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) I've found out that there is no MNB available, and by default it's SVM, however NB is the linear model, isn't it?

So if my likelihood parameters (with Laplacian smoothing) can be estimated as
[image: MNB likelihood param estimation]

Can I update my parameters with SGD and minimize the cost function?

[image]

Please let me know if SGD is irrelevant here. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
So I got the answer and hope that I got it right, that MNB's parameters are updated by the word occurence in the given input text (like tf-idf). But I still don't understand clearly why we can't use SGD for MNB training. I'd understand it if it's explained in explicit description or with some mathematical interpretation. Thanks

Comment: That would be a question for thread **CrossValidated**

Answer (score 0):

> In sklearn I've found out that there is no MNB available

Multinomial naive Bayes is implemented in scikit-learn. There is no gradient descent to use. This implementation just uses relative frequencies counts (with smoothing) to find the parameters of the model in a single pass (which the standard and most efficient way to fit an MNB model):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant "there is no MNB available" for SGDClassifier module, where SGD uses SVM by default. So I thought that we can train our any model with SGD, because it minimizes the cost function.. with gradients.